# How can I get a deep element of a json string in scala?

Tags: json, scala

I am using Scala to parse json with a structure like this:

```
{
 "root": {
  "metadata": {
   "name": "Farmer John",
   "hasTractor": false
  },
  "plants": {
   "corn": 137.137,
   "soy": 0.45
  },
  "animals": {
   "cow": 4,
   "sheep": 12,
   "pig": 1
  }
 }
}
```

And I am currently using the `org.json` library to parse it, like this:

```
val jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString) // Where jsonString is the above json tree
```

But when I run something like `jsonObject.get("root.metadata.name")` then I get the error:

```
JSONObject["root.metadata.name"] not found.  
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["root.metadata.name"] not found.
```

I suspect I can get the objects one at a time by splitting up that path, but that sounds tedious and I assume a better json library already exists. Is there a way to easily get the data the way I am trying to or is there a better library to use that works better with Scala?

Comment: You can define a couple of **case classes** that represents the model and use something like **circe**, **play-json**, **jsonitter-scala**, **upickle**, etc to transform that String into an instance of a case class and then manipulate the data using normal Scala.

Comment: The data I am parsing is not regular and generally cant be represented by a case class

Comment: Then still most of those libraries support a way of traversing the JSON and manipulating it. However, SO is not a place to ask for recommendations. Search for them pick one that you feel you will like and then if you have problems edit this question or open a new one focused on that library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to solve it using `JsonPath` like this:

```
val document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(jsonString): Object
val value = JsonPath.read(document, "$.root.metadata.name"): Any
```

Comment: As mentioned in the post, `JsonPath`

Answer (score 0):

The `JSONObject` you are using is deprecated. The deprecation message sends you to [The Scala Library Index](https://index.scala-lang.org/). I'll demonstrate how this can be done in [play-json](https://index.scala-lang.org/playframework/play-json/play-json/2.9.1?target=_2.13). Let's assume that the json above is stored at `jsonString`, so we can do:

```scala
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
val path = JsPath \ "root" \ "metadata" \ "name"

path(json) match {
  case Nil =>
    ??? // path does nont exist
  case values =>
    println(s"Values are: $values")
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/Luh08R75TieohLuBwdzn6Q).